# extJs - How to remove the row selection in grid after grid store reloaded

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

In my application, I have used gridpanel. When I am trying to reload the grid store the checkbox selection remains same after the store reloaded.

How to deselect the selection after the store reloaded?

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does this selection visible in the UI ? because i am also stucked on the same lines.  for me the selection is not visible on the UI whereas i can retrieve it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to the store on the `load` event. In that listener, get the grid's selection model, and call [`deselectAll`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model-method-deselectAll).

`this.getStore().on('load', function() {
  this.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
}, this)`